How do you make a test to be skipped in CPP Unit
I am working with a C++ project in which I am using CPP UNIT for unit testing. I need specific test cases to be skipped based on a command line argument.
I have used CPP_ASSERT_FAIL() and returning early in the test case. But the test is counted as failure or successfull in the respective cases. Could you suggest me a way to mark this test as skipped.

It seems you might register test manually (and organize them by suite), so do it according to command line?

In CPPUnit, there's no built-in way to mark tests as "skipped" directly, as it doesn’t have native support for test skipping. However, you can work around this by using an assumption and creating a custom output that signifies the test was skipped.
Define a Skip Macro: Create a macro to check if the test should be skipped based on the condition. This macro can print a message indicating the test was skipped, then return from the test function without marking it as pass or fail.
#define SKIP_IF(condition, message) \
    if (condition) { \
        std::cout << "[SKIPPED] " << message << std::endl; \
        return; \
    }



In CPPUnit, there's no built-in way to mark tests as "skipped" directly, as it doesn’t have native support for test skipping.

@Shahul Hameed statement is correct!
What you can try to do one way is that dynamically adding tests based on conditions.
class CustomTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture {
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(CustomTest);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(test1);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(test2);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
    void test1() {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(true);
    }

    void test2() {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(true);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;

    bool skipTests = false;

    if (argc > 1 && std::string(argv[1]) == "--skip") {
        skipTests = true;
    }

    if (!skipTests) {
        runner.addTest(MyTest::suite());
    } else {
        std::cout << "Tests were skipped due to command line argument.\n";
    }

    runner.run();
    return 0;
}

